# How to install OS onto a MacBook Pro with no OS installed

Tags: macos, bootcamp, windows

I have MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.3 17" Early 2011 (Model: A1279). 
Out of ignorance I've delete the previous OS (Yosemite) to install Windows – I had some difficulties but i could do it.

The problem is that Windows couldn't detect my macbook drivers (video card , network card ...).

After that I realized that there's a tool called Boot Camp Assistant that makes it possible to install Windows on a Mac.

The problem now is that I don't have any OS X on my machine. I've downloaded a couple of Yosemite DMG files and made a bootable disk using TransMac, but it didn't work.

First dmg file: didn't detect the boot usb at all.
Second dmg File: no pass sign after booting from the USB in the loading phase .

Any ideas how to install any OS onto my machine?

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201314 For future reference, it's generally better to do your research **before** committing to a course of action :/

Comment: What version of Windows are you trying to install? I should be possible to install Windows without having any version of OS X installed. I also assume your optical (DVD) drive still works.

Comment: i'm not trying to install windows , i'm trying to install yosomite or any Mac OS , to install windows in it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EzOr, first read the note a the end of this document.

### The procedure given below is for 2011 and older Macs with a working optical (DVD) drive.

While it is possible to install Windows on your Mac without an other operating system, you would need to install the "Boot Camp Support Software" after installing Windows. In your case, it would be best to first start with the OS X that was originally shipped with your Mac, then install Windows. The steps are outlined below.

1. To reinstall the version of OS X that was shipped with your Mac, you
   need to boot using [OS X Internet Recovery](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314). Once booted, use the
   Disk Utility application to partition the internal drive with a
   single "Mac OS Extended (Journaled)" partition using "GUID Partition
   Table" scheme. The reinstall OS X.
2. Once booted to OS X, use the Boot Camp Assistant application to
   "Download the latest "Windows support software form Apple". This
   will download the "Boot Camp Support Software" to a USB flash drive.
3. You will need a 64 bit Window installation DVD. If you have an iso
   file, you will need to burn this to a DVD.
4. Enter the following command in a Terminal application window.

   ```
   sudo bless --device /dev/disk0 --setBoot --legacy
   ```

   This will allow the Windows operating system to boot properly.
5. With the DVD inserted in the optical (DVD) drive and the "Boot Camp
   Support Software" flash drive inserted in a USB port, restart the
   Mac and hold down the <kbd>option</kbd> key. When the Startup
   Manager displays the DVD icon with the label "Windows", select this
   icon to start installing Windows.
6. You will need to navigate to open a Command Prompt window. The
   procedure varies depending on the version of Windows you are
   installing. (For Windows 7, see instructions given after these
   steps) In this window, enter the following commands.

   ```
   diskpart
   select disk 0
   clean
   convert mbr
   exit
   setup
   ```
7. Install Windows. When finished, install the "Boot Camp Support
   Software" on the USB flash drive. This should complete the
   installation of windows.

### Opening a Command Prompt window using a Windows 7 installation DVD

Boot from the Windows 7 DVD. Press the space bar, if prompted to "Press any key to boot from CD or DVD."

When the display below appears, click the "Next" button.

[image: 100]

When the display below appears, select "Repair your computer".

[image: 101]

With the button "Use recovery tools that can help fix problems starting Windows." selected, click the Next button.

[image: 102]

Select the "Command Prompt" option.

[image: 103]

### If you have already install Windows and need to install the "Boot Camp Support Software", this may help.

Here I assume you have installed a 64 bit version of Windows. You can try downloading the ["Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5621"](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US). If you can not download this using your Mac, use a different computer.

After installing the ["Boot Camp Support Software 5.1.5621](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1720?locale=en_US), you will need to *bless* your Mac. Open the Control Panel and then open the Boot Camp icon. Select the Windows icon and then select the button to restart the Mac.

Comment: thanks for your answer David , however i can't enter the OS X Recovery, since when i hold down Command (⌘)-R , i enter the windows recovery (cause i have windows installed) that's the problem .

Comment: The startup key sequences have nothing to do with the installed operating system. These key sequences are read by a program called firmware stored on the logic board of your Mac. This program does not change unless you update the firmware, which you have not done. Besides, you are suppose to hold down **Option-Command-R** keys to start OS X Internet Recovery. (This is 3 different keys.) In your case, holding down Command (⌘)-R pair of keys will not work.

Comment: Wow i was stuck for days cause of that , thanks a lot mate !

Comment: however after i enter my password after 10 minute if the globe turning i got the 2002F error ...
tried to change password to wpa2 with no success .

Comment: I don't suppose there is any way you can connect your Mac to the internet using an ethernet cable. Otherwise, the WiFi should work if you know the correct passphrase and the connection is using WPA or WPA2. For other WiFi requirements, see the Apple web site: [How to reinstall OS X](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204904).